# Finding exception in Objective c code

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am debugging my application on iphone (OS 2.0) using X-code 3.1 iphone SDK 3.0 beta 5 . My application crashes giving message
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: index (8) beyond bounds (8)'
2009-05-23 17:13:32.304 myApp[405:5a07] Stack: (
    808163835,
    806099672,
    807978623,
    807978527,
    812332907,
    812067179,
    812067103,
    126035,
    812081649,
    812081343,
    826526801
)

In gdb when I give commands
(gdb) info line 126035
Line number 126035 is out of range for "/Users/videomac/manish/EXPLab/2009-05-18-12-27 myApp/main.m".

(gdb) info line *126035
Line 527 of "/Users/videomac/manish/EXPLab/2009-05-18-12-27 myApp/Classes/PlaybackThread/Playback.m" starts at address 0x1ec52 <-[Playback startPlaybackThread:]+514> and ends at 0x1ec6a <-[Playback startPlaybackThread:]+538>.

does that means the crash is due to code in my method [Playback startPlaybackThread:]
then  what is meaning of the no +514 and +538 do they signify line no?

Is there any other way to locate reason of crashes?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find where your exception is happening is to set breakpoints on -[NSException raise] and objc_exception_throw in gdb. Then you'll break as soon as it happens, and you can examine the stack at that point.

Comment: how to set breakpoints on -[NSException raise] and objc_exception_throw in gdb

Answer (score 1):

About the first error you mention, from [-insertObject:atIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject:atIndex:) documentation:

> **Important**: Raises an [NSRangeException](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSRangeException)
>   if *index* is greater than the number of
>   elements in the array.

I would look for calls of this method, trying to find which one causes the error.

Numbers +514 and +538 give an offset from the code of instructions just before.